# autobahn websocket connection with remote server failed

Tags: websocket, autobahn

I am using autobahn websocket library in android app and it turns out that connection works well in subnet like 192.168.1.XXX,but why it doesn't work when I tried to use the remote IP address .

Comment: Could you provide a bit more detail - and an actual question? As is, it's hard to know what precisely you want to know.

Comment: When I run the autobahn echo  example code listening the port 9000 on the localhost  on my local PC ,it works very well ,and  my android phone could connect with it as well.But when I put the server.py onto my remote server with a unique IP ,after I changed the android websocket connection wsuri to the remote server's IP address,the connection doesn't work,any clue about that how to fix this?thanks